# Get count of games and display the players who played half of games

Tags: sql, sql-server

i Need help in these tables, i want SQL statement to give me this :

the players who played in half or more of the games, lets assume that we have 6 different games in 'GameType' table ... So I want to display all players who played 3 or more games.

like :

```
ID     surName     number of games played
1      test1               3
2      test2               4
3      test3               3
4      test4               6
```

this what i done until now:

```
SELECT        dbo.Player.ID, dbo.Player.surName, count(DISTINCT 
dbo.PlayerInAGame.gameTypeName) AS games_played, count(DISTINCT 
dbo.Game.gameTypeName) AS games_count
FROM            dbo.Player INNER JOIN
                     dbo.PlayerInAGame ON dbo.Player.ID = 
dbo.PlayerInAGame.playerID INNER JOIN
dbo.Game ON dbo.PlayerInAGame.gameTypeName = dbo.Game.gameTypeName AND 
dbo.PlayerInAGame.gameDateTime = dbo.Game.gameStartDateTime
GROUP BY dbo.Player.ID, dbo.Player.surName, dbo.Game.DealerInGame
```

here is the tables:

```
 create table Dealer
( 
number int identity(1000,1) primary key,
firstName nvarchar(20) not null,
surName nvarchar(20) not null,
birthDate date not null,
startWorkingDate date not null,
ID char(9) check(ID like replicate('[0-9]',9)) not null unique, 
check(datediff(year,birthDate,startWorkingDate)>=24) 
) 

create table GameType
( 
name nvarchar(20) primary key,
description nvarchar(20) not null,
minimumPlayers tinyint check (minimumPlayers > 0) not null,
maximumPlayers tinyint check (maximumPlayers > 0) not null, 
check(minimumPlayers <= maximumPlayers)
) 

create table Game
( 
gameTypeName nvarchar(20) references GameType(name) on delete cascade,
gameStartDateTime datetime,
gameEndTime time,
DealerInGame int not null references Dealer(number),
primary key(gameTypeName,gameStartDateTime) 
) 

create table Player
( 
ID char(9) primary key,
firstName nvarchar(20) not null,
surName nvarchar(20) not null,
city nvarchar(20) not null,
birthDate date check(datediff(year,birthDate,getdate())>=18) not null, 
preferred nvarchar(20) references GameType(name) on delete set null
) 

create table PlayerInAGame
( 
playerID char(9) references Player(ID),
gameTypeName nvarchar(20),
gameDateTime datetime,
betAmount int check(betAmount>0) not null,
winLosAmount int,
check((winLosAmount = -betAmount) or (winLosAmount>=betAmount)),
foreign key(gameTypeName,gameDateTime) references 
Game(gameTypeName,gameStartDateTime), primary 
key(playerID,gameTypeName,gameDateTime) ) 

create table PlayerDealerRelation
(
dealerNumber int references Dealer(number) on delete cascade,
playerID char(9) references Player(ID),
relationType char(1) check(relationType in ('P','G','B','C','U','N')), 
primary key(dealerNumber,playerID) 
)
```

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING etc.

Comment: Your question confuses me... do you want the player who have played half of the games or half of the game types? And do you want the number of games or game types? And how should the two be put together? I think it may also help to understand this, if you show what you've got already.

Comment: @stickybit, yes i want ` the players who have played half of the games`
all the players who played half or more of the games as a list, `ID,surName, number of games played`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query in the question gives you the correct count, then it is very easy to add an extra filter that would leave only those rows where `games_played` is more than half of `games_count`.

Just add `HAVING`:

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Player.ID, 
    dbo.Player.surName, 
    count(DISTINCT dbo.PlayerInAGame.gameTypeName) AS games_played,
    count(DISTINCT dbo.Game.gameTypeName) AS games_count
FROM            
    dbo.Player 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PlayerInAGame ON dbo.Player.ID = dbo.PlayerInAGame.playerID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Game 
        ON dbo.PlayerInAGame.gameTypeName = dbo.Game.gameTypeName 
        AND dbo.PlayerInAGame.gameDateTime = dbo.Game.gameStartDateTime
GROUP BY dbo.Player.ID, dbo.Player.surName, dbo.Game.DealerInGame 
HAVING 
    count(DISTINCT dbo.PlayerInAGame.gameTypeName) > 
    count(DISTINCT dbo.Game.gameTypeName) / 2
```